# Groovy: merging two XML files with GPathResult.appendNode(node) does not work

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper

I need to write a script that takes several XML files and performs some operations basing on their contents. To make it easier to go through all the elements I wanted to merge all files into one XML tree (only in memory). I've tried using `appendNode()` method but I've encountered very strange behaviour. Here's the snippet I use to show the problem:

```groovy
def slurper = new XmlSlurper()
def a = slurper.parseText("<a></a>")
def b = slurper.parseText("<b>foo</b>")
a.appendNode(b)

println XmlUtil.serialize(a)

a."**".each { println (it.name()) }
```

It outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><a>
  <b>foo</b>
</a>

a
```

Serialized XML is correct but I don't get `<b>` from the iterator.

However, if I add this line after appending:

```groovy
a = slurper.parseText(XmlUtil.serialize(a))
```

output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><a>
  <b>foo</b>
</a>

a
b
```

`<b>` is there as I expect it to be.

What am I missing here? Why parsing and serializing again changed the output? I'm new to Groovy so I imagine it can be something obvious, please help me understand why it happens. Or maybe there is a better way to merge XML files?

Comment: how you get the iterator?

Comment: Forgot to add last line, sorry, its already there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because [`XmlSlurper.parse(String text)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html#parse-java.lang.String-) returns [`GPathResult`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.html) which is:

> Base class for representing lazy evaluated GPath expressions.

And according to [Groovy XML processing documentation](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html):

> `XmlSlurper` evaluates the structure lazily. So if you update the xml you’ll have to evaluate the whole tree again.

That's why you have to re-evalutate XML tree with

```groovy
a = slurper.parseText(XmlUtil.serialize(a))
```

to get your expression working.

If you use [`XmlParser`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlParser.html) on the other hand you will get it working without re-evaluation of XML tree, e.g.

```groovy
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

XmlParser root = new XmlParser()
def a = root.parseText("<a></a>")
def b = root.parseText("<b>foo</b>")

a.append(b)

println XmlUtil.serialize(a)

a."**".each { println (it.name()) }
```

#### Output

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><a>
  <b>foo</b>
</a>

a
b
```